# ES6 - Get all activity objects of same day [ difference less than or equal to 1 day ]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of activity objects [ javascript - es6 ].
One property is ActivityTime and I am looking for the best way to get all objects with activity time of same day.
That is all objects with activity time difference is less than or equal to 1 day.  I would like to do it using latest Es6 features if possible, appreciate the help.

```
 const activities =    [
      {
        "ActivityID": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "ActivityTime ": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
      },
      {
        "ActivityID": 26,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "West",
        "ActivityTime ": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
      },
      {
        "ActivityID": 27,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "ActivityTime ": "2017-02-01T00:02:01.001Z",
        "MeasureValue": 3
      }

    ]
```

Here I expect objects with ACtivityID 25 & 27 as they belong to same date [difference less than or equal to 24 hours ]

How to do this in the cleanest way using Es6 features ?

I tried below...but didnt work

```
const datesAreOnSameDay = (first, second) => {
    console.log("First Date: " + new Date(first.ActivityTime ));
    console.log("Second Date: " + new Date(second.ActivityTime ));
    new Date(first.ActivityTime ).getFullYear() === new Date(second.ActivityTime ).getFullYear() &&
        new Date(first.ActivityTime ).getMonth() === new Date(second.ActivityTime ).getMonth() &&
        new Date(first.ActivityTime ).getDate() === new Date(second.ActivityTime ).getDate();
}

const filtered = activities .filter(datesAreOnSameDay);

console.log(filtered);
```

I tried to use a filter function assuming that it will take two objects each and will check if they are of same date.  But somehow it prints second argument as Invalid Date.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, there is a lot of typos in your exemple and no effort were made on the presentation. For the next time please make sure it is suitable and easy to read for everyone.

On the other side I join @Andreas on this one, have you made a little bit of search on google "Filter an array of object javascript" you will find plenty of solutions.

Comment: @ChainList - I am sorry for the bad alignment. I am not that used to stackoverflow. Also I have tried my level best to find a solution..but unfortunately couldnt. Thats why came here : )

Comment: @Andreas -  I will definitely look into the formatting as I am new here. Forgive me this time.

Comment: Your `first` argument will be the value from the array. What `second` argument do you want to compare it against? The current day (today)? Some other day?

Comment: Hi Bergi.. I was trying to compare it with other objects. Means, in second argument, I though another object will be taken.  But seems I was wrong.

Comment: @Andreas - Do you have any answer suggestion please ?  I think I have corrected format issues based on your instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
            const activities = [
                { 
                    "ActivityID": 25,
                    "AlertType": 1,
                    "Area": "North",
                    "ActivityTime": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
                    "MeasureValue": -1
                },
                {
                    "ActivityID": 26,
                    "AlertType": 1,
                    "Area": "West",
                    "ActivityTime": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
                    "MeasureValue": -1
                },
                { 
                    "ActivityID": 27,
                    "AlertType": 1,
                    "Area": "North",
                    "ActivityTime": "2017-02-01T00:02:01.001Z",
                    "MeasureValue": 3
                }
            ]
            function filter(arr, arg, _filter){
                let ret_arr = []
                arr.forEach(element => {
                    if(_filter(element, arg))
                        ret_arr.push(element);
                });
                return ret_arr
            }
            let new_arr = filter(activities, new Date("2017-02-01T00:00:00.001Z"), (x, y) => {
                const gap = Math.abs(new Date(x.ActivityTime) - y) / 3600000
                    //getting difference in milliseconds, then converting it to hours
                if (gap >= -24 && gap <= 24)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            });
            console.log(new_arr)
```

**You can iterate through your array passing ActivityTime to this filter function and getting instances with similar time like this**

```
            activities.forEach(elemnt => {
                const same = filter(activities, new Date(elemnt.ActivityTime), (x, y) => {
                    const gap = Math.abs(new Date(x.ActivityTime) - y) / 3600000
                    //getting difference in milliseconds, then converting it to hours
                    if (gap >= -24 && gap <= 24)
                        return true;
                    else return false;
                });
                if(same.length > 1){
                    //do whatever you want
                }
            });
```

Comment: Arthur..awesome..! got the output correctly. Before marking it as THE answer, just wanted to clarify one thing.  Sorry if it might sound silly.  What will be the value of 'y' in the filter  function ?  new Date(x.ActivityTime) - y .

Comment: Whatever you want to pass to the filter function as arg you're gonna get it back in your arrow function. In this particular example we pass a Date object to the function filter as 'arg' and then get it back in our arrow function as 'y' and continue by finding the difference. We could just do (new Date(x.ActivityTime) - new Date("2017-02-01T00:00:00.001Z")) for example, but this will incur a redundant Date instantiation every time arrow function gets called and plus you won't be able to use it in any other situation where you need to modify logic of the filter.

Comment: That makes sense...Thank you very much Arthur. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For today:

```
activities.filter((activity) => {
  return (new Date(activity.ActivityTime) >= moment().startOf('day') && new Date(activity.ActivityTime) < moment().endOf('day'));
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  May I please know if there is any other way using "only ES6"   instead of using others like moment.js ?

Comment: I would recommend for all operations with time and date to use momentJS library, and use Date constructor only when you need convert text to date, or similiar simple cases. There lots of magic and inconvenicence how native Date works in js, not to mention different implementation of some edge cases in different browsers.

Comment: Ivan.. It didnt work...Please note, I cannot pass any particular date as input. It should check all objects and find entries belong to same date.  Not within a date range.

Comment: momentJS library is quite heavy though. I you got your app compiled using webpack, try to use `date-fns` instead. Great tree shaking.